# THREE.js several thousand meshes adjust opacity based on distance to focal point

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

I want to adjust the opacity of my meshes based on their proximity to a focal point. Right now, I'm just iterating through the meshes and adjusting their opacity based on their distance to the focal point.

In pseudocode::

```
set_opacities: () ->
  for mesh in @group.children
    # we have the camera looking at this point "focus"
    # objects in the focal point should become opaque
    distance_to_focus = mesh.position.distanceTo(focus)
    opacity = @options.delta / distance_to_focus
    mesh.material.opacity = opacity
```

This works fine with a small number of meshes but can get pretty expensive when there are several thousand meshes. I haven't investigated shaders too deeply. But, I feel that it is time to make use of shaders to improve performance. How would I change the opacity of a mesh based on its distance to a focal point using shaders? Does THREE have builtins for this case or do I write my own?

Are there any other strategies that might be worth investigating? Merging the meshes is not ideal in this case because I continuously add more so it becomes expensive to recompute the entire geometry constantly, I think.